# Is there a way to see the total supply of coins?

Tags: blockchain

I ask because if there is anonymous transactions how is one (without the Private Key) going to see an address?

Comment: I believe there is - but can someone confirm that this would still be possible after RingCT come in by default?

Comment: RingCT will not hide the coinbase transaction output amounts, so you will be able to tell the coin supply in the same way as before.

Answer (score 5):

The untraceability of the monero blockchain is achieved by the use of ring signatures to sign transactions. The block reward does not have the ambiguity of where those coins came from. They came to existence as the reward for finding that block.

Therefore, it is possible to know how many monero are in existence simply by adding all the block reward (or coinbase) transactions in the monero blockchain.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a built-in way to verify this manually: [get_coinbase_tx_sum](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_coinbase_tx_sum).

For example, running

`$ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18081/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_coinbase_tx_sum","params":{"height":0,"count":100}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

Will return the total supply after the first 100 blocks. Note the result is in the picnoero, where 1 XMR = 10e12 picnoero.